# SwiftUI: Update struct View when calling mutating func

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiview

New to Switch. I need to implement an Analog Clock with auto-updating every second to the current time (like a typical analog clock).

Drawing the Views etc is no problem. But I'm having troubles auto-updating the time.

**View**

```
struct ClockView: View {
    var viewModel: ClockViewModel
    var clock:ClockViewModel.TransformedClock
    var size: CGFloat
    
    @State var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
            .fill(.white)
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
            .overlay{
                GeometryReader{ geometry in
                    let radius = geometry.size.width/2
                    let midX = geometry.safeAreaInsets.top + radius
                    let midY = geometry.safeAreaInsets.leading + radius
                    
                    ClockFace(size: size, radius: radius, x: midX, y: midY)
                    
                    ClockHand(type: .second,    angle: clock.secondAngle,   x: midX,    y: midY,    length: radius-size*0.04,      size: size)
                        .onReceive(timer){ _ in updateAngleHere}
              
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ClockHand:View{
    let type: ClockHandType
    @State var angle: Double
    var x: CGFloat
    var y: CGFloat
    var length: CGFloat
    var size: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .fill(type.getColor())
            .frame(width: size*type.getWidth(), height: length )
            .position(x: x, y: y)
            .offset(y: -length/2)
            .rotationEffect(Angle.degrees(angle))
    }
    
    mutating func update(angle: Double) {
        print("calling   \(self.angle)")
        self.angle = angle
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class ClockViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private var model: ClockModel
    
    init(){
        model = ClockViewModel.initClocks()
    }
    
    static func initClock()->ClockModel {
        let places = [
            "Europe/Bern",
        ]
        return ClockModel(number: places.count){ index in
            places[index]
        }
    }

    var activeClock: TransformedClock{
        TransformedClock(clock: model.activeWorldClock!)
    }
    
    
    struct TransformedClock:Identifiable{
        var id:Int
        var secondAngle:Double
        var clock:ClockModel.WorldClock
        
        init(clock:ClockModel.WorldClock){
            let second = clock.calendar.component(.second, from: Date())
            self.clock  = clock
            self.id     = clock.id
            self.secondAngle = Double(second)/60.0*360
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
struct ClockModel{
    
    var worldClocks: [WorldClock]
    
    init(number: Int, timeFactory: (Int)->String){
        worldClocks = [WorldClock]()
        for index in 0..<number{
            let place = timeFactory(index)
            var calendar = Calendar.current
            
            worldClocks.append(
                WorldClock(
                    id:         index,
                    calendar:   calendar,
                    place:      formatPlaceString(place)
                )
            )
        }
    }
    
    struct WorldClock:Identifiable {
        var calendar: Calendar
        var place: String
    }
}
```

Find my code above. First of all, I just would like to move the ClockHand for seconds to different positions. For this, I've been told to use a `timer` and make use of `onReceive`. My first idea was to call a mutating func of that struct in the closure - but since I can't seem to specifically call it on that struct, I guess it's the wrong option.

So, I need to find a way to teach my second-ClockFace struct to update / redraw itself, whenever I call the mutating func.

Examples I've found only shown functions outside a struct...
Any inut would be much appreciated.

Comment: This isn’t enough code to reproduce the issue. Please include a [mre]

Comment: any specific scenario why you are using mutating function you can use  @Binding var angle: Double

Comment: @jnpdx Updated code

Comment: @Vaisakh hm how would I update the angles through the closure in onReceive then?

Comment: Shouldn't 
    var viewModel: ClockViewModel
be @ObservedObject var viewModel: ClockViewModel ?

Comment: Can you try changing like below

@ State var clock:ClockViewModel.TransformedClock

ClockHand(type: .second,    angle: $clock.secondAngle,   x: midX,    y: midY,    length: radius-size*0.04,      size: size)
                        .onReceive(timer){ _ in  clock.secondAngle = clock.secondAngle + 10}




struct ClockHand:View{
    @Binding var angle: Double
    …..

}

Above code will work in your scenario. But better to move your timer logic to viewmodel and every seconds update the angle.

Comment: There's a bunch of missing code that won't let me compile what you have, but I'llc echo the above comment that `mutating` should *not* be used on SwiftUI views. That's the point of having `@State` to persist state across iterations of the view. At the least, you should remove the `mutating` keyword from `update`